# Formatted Text in UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, sdk, uiscrollview

What i Need to do for our project is to Display several UIScrollViews in a View and weithin the scrollView a Headline and a Short Text.

I Know how to add a Label to the UIscrollview, but how Gould i handle the Case that the Headline-Label is too Long and wraps to a Second Line.

Answer (score 4):

You can determine the space needed for the headline text by calling `-[NSString sizeWithFont:]` or one of its variants. Then size and position the labels dynamically in your code (and set their `numberOfLines` property to `0`).

Alternatives:

- Use a `UIWebView` to display formatted text (HTML).
- Use Core Graphics to draw the text directly into the view (e.g. `[NSString drawAtPoint:withFont:]`).
- Use Core Text to format and draw the text (quite complicated).

Comment: This post covers my thoughts and then some.